# animate an image (ie grow in and fade in at the same time)

Tags: animation, fadein, codenameone

I am creating a splash screen. So far I can achieve either grow-in effect or fade-in effect. It is not working while trying to get both animation at the same time.

```
//zooms or grows the image
findImageViewerSplash(f).growShrink(1000);
//for fade in effect
findContainerImageViewer(f).animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2000, 0);
```

Used an image viewer to get the grow effect. Here image viewer component is inside ContainerImageViewer. If I comment out one of the line, it works but implementing both is not working.
Thankyou

Exception when setUIID to scaleImageLabel.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:100)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1149)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:966)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.components.ScaleImageLabel.calcPreferredSize(ScaleImageLabel.java:83)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.preferredSizeImpl(Component.java:1930)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.preferredSize(Component.java:1965)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.setPreferredSize(Component.java:735)
    at userclasses.StateMachine.beforeSplashScreen(StateMachine.java:178)
    at generated.StateMachineBase.beforeShow(StateMachineBase.java:883)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.showForm(UIBuilder.java:2514)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.showForm(UIBuilder.java:2561)
    at generated.StateMachineBase.startApp(StateMachineBase.java:60)
    at generated.StateMachineBase.<init>(StateMachineBase.java:31)
    at generated.StateMachineBase.<init>(StateMachineBase.java:106)
    at userclasses.StateMachine.<init>(StateMachine.java:78)
    at com.ruslanVodka_CapitalEye.myapp.RuslanApp.start(RuslanApp.java:23)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These effects are exclusive to one another and you can run them in parallel.

You don't actually need the `growShrink` call as the `animateLayout*` calls will grow/shrink based on your preferred size definition.

Following is a sample that produces a "grow" effect with animate layout:

```
Form hi = new Form("Grow", new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER));
int w = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();
ScaleImageLabel dukeLabel = new ScaleImageLabel(duke);
dukeLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w / 3, w / 3));
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, dukeLabel);
hi.addShowListener((e) -> {
    dukeLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, w));
    dukeLabel.getParent().animateLayout(5000);
});

hi.show();
```

Comment: i dont get it how can I grow/shrink using animateLayout? can u give me an eg.

Comment: Animate layout moves the components to their new size/position so if you just set the preferred size of the component it should grow to fit the new size. Notice you can also use animateUnlayout which allows you to animate to any arbitrary location/size.

Comment: findImageViewerSplash(f).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth/3, screenWidth/3));  
findContainer(f).animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2000, 0); 
findImageViewerSplash(f).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenWidth));  
It has no change. Here container is in borderlayout. if I change the layout into flow layout, the imageviewersplash component moves from left to right.But i want to change the size and not the postion

Comment: Added a code sample that does just that. Duke is just the icon image that I copied into the src directory.

Comment: thankyou so much... one more thing if I set uiid of scaleImageLabel it gives NullPointerException
 at com.codename1.components.ScaleImageLabel.calcPreferredSize(ScaleImageLabel.java:83)

Comment: If your library up to date? Try update client libraries in the Codename One settings section.

Comment: Line 83 is an old line. You need to do update client libs to fetch the latest version.